# Cross addition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to apply cross addition (OR) in my pandas dataframe like below.

Input:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  1
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  1
1  1  1  1  1
2  0  1  0  1
3  1  1  1  1
```

So far I can achieve using this,

```
cols=df.columns
n=len(cols)
df1=pd.concat([df]*n,ignore_index=True).eq(1)
df2= pd.concat([df.T]*n,axis=1,ignore_index=True).eq(1)
df2.columns=cols
df2=df2.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1|df2).astype(int)
```

I think there is much more simpler way to handle this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy` `|` operation with broadcast as:

```
data = df.values
df = pd.DataFrame((data.T | data), columns=df.columns)
```

Or using [`np.logical_or`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html#numpy.logical_or) as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.logical_or(data,data.T).astype(int), columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
print(df)

   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  1
1  1  1  1  1
2  0  1  0  1
3  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy solution:

First extract first row to `1d` array with `iloc` and then [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by `a[:, None]` for change shape to `Mx1`:

```
a = df.iloc[0].values
df = pd.DataFrame(a | a[:, None], columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  1
1  1  1  1  1
2  0  1  0  1
3  1  1  1  1
```